# Как править SSDT-пакеты в VS 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Имею VS 2015 Pro, установлен Sql Server Data Tools, но имеющиеся *.dtsx пакеты открываются в виде XML-файла. Как открыть эти файлы в визуальном редакторе?

[image: SSDT]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас должно быть установлено дополнение SQL Server Data Tools Business Intelligence (SSDT-BI) https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssdt/2015/09/01/sql-server-data-tools-preview-update-for-august-2015/  Версия 14.0.60413.0

Comment: Добавил скрин в вопрос. Это то что надо или что-то сверху еще необходимо установить?

Comment: Попробуйте поставить версию 14.0.60413.0

Comment: Удивительно, но это работает. Спасибо